# Changing Wordpress Domains / URLs

Tags: wordpress

I'm being really cautious how I manage a switchover from an existing WordPress site to a new one.

In a nutshell....

I have designed a new wordpress website, let's call it NewWebsite.com
I have an existing website, let's call that MyBrand.com

I want to be able to point my domain name, MyBrand.com, at the NewWebsite.com server. So that MyBrand.com takes you to the newly designed WordPress instance.

I'm hosting both on TSOHost, they are both standard WordPress.org installs and I have access to root.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.  I've done this once before and it ended badly, so treading carefully.

Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: What does 'ended badly' mean exactly? Is this an SEO related question or did the switch break the site in some way?

Comment: "takes you to the newly designed WordPress instance" like a forwarding to another url: from MyBrand.com to NewWebsite.com?
If so, you can use the .htaccess file to get that working.
If you are new to this, a closer look at forwarding and redirection - https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-creating-redirects-in-wordpress/ - may help you.

Comment: thank you both for the responses.